# Adding Video Collapses the design

Tags: html, css, iframe, video

I have a section in my HTML page with a height of `500px;`.In the center of the section there are Div's which displays some texts.Now as per my requirement i have to add the video as background of this section such that video should be played in the Background with 100% width and 500px height and text should be displayed on the top of the playing video.

But on adding the video ,My design is getting collapsed.My texts are getting displayed beyond 500px height and video is displaying around 250px down from the start of the main section..

Here is my video HTML>.

```
 <div class="auto-resizable-iframe">
    <div>
        <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

and Here is my fiddle link   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nq8sa2kw/1/)  .Please help me guys i am struggling from long time for this ..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a change in your css the width should be change from max-width to min-width http://jsfiddle.net/nq8sa2kw/2/ But the problem is that it makes the video unclickable you have to figure out something on your own

```
.auto-resizable-iframe {
position:absolute;
min-width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: OK. Actaully in your fiddle the is some space in green color .I need my video to be shown from there..How to do it?

Comment: I have removed the Clickable issue and now the video is playing but how to display it from the top.?

Comment: @HansalMehta add top:0; then the video begins from the top                  .auto-resizable-iframe {
    position:absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    top:0;
}

Comment: Thanks Sir its came up.One small change that i want is that there is green color coming in the bottom after the Video .I want to remove that one How to do it?Here is the Updated fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/nq8sa2kw/3/

Comment: @HansalMehta a few  changes has been made http://jsfiddle.net/nq8sa2kw/4/ -- .auto-resizable-iframe > div i changed the padding to 100%; and in the .main section height was redused to 100px;